# Grouping Threaded Comments fetched from database

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am following the following tutorial on displaying hierarchical data from database http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships

so far i have the following table

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    parent = relationship("Node", remote_side=[id])
```

And the following entries in mysql

```
id  parent_id   data
1   NULL            root
2   1 [->]          child1
3   1 [->]          child2
4   3 [->]          subchild1
5   3 [->]          subchild 2
6   1 [->]          child3
7   NULL            root2
8   NULL            root3
9   7 [->]          subchild0froot2
10  8 [->]          subchildofroot3
11  1 [->]          child4
```

I want to retrieve data in a format that will be suitable for comments e.g root -> child1 -> child2 ->(subchild1->subchild2)->child4

So far i have been able to retrieve the children of a parent through this query

```
nodealias = aliased(Node)
qry = session.query(nodealias,Node).\
                join(nodealias, Node.parent).\
                filter(and_(Node.postid==45))



print qry
for x,y in qry:
    print x.data
    print y.data

    print "...."

And it displays

root
child1
....
root
child2
....
child2
subchild1
....
child2
subchild 2
....
root
child3
....
root
child4
....
```

I want to group this results in the following manner

```
root
....
child1
....
child2
subchild1
subchild 2
....
child3
....
child4
....
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the root without his child, you should use an OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

For grouping your child by parent, you should use a GROUP BY.

So, your query will be:

```
  qry = session.query(nodealias,Node).\
        outerjoin(nodealias, Node.parent).\
        group_by(Node.parent).all()
```

Then, to have separator beetween your first level leaf, you have to make a test on parent.id when iterating through your results. Don't forget to check NoneType parent because your are including the root in your resultset.

```
  for parent, child in qry:
    if parent is None or parent.id != 1:
      print child.data
    else:
      print '...'
      print child.data
```

For better representation with 3rd level leaf, you could apply a similar technic by checking parent.id != 2.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think this will be too complicated to render in mako

Comment: I don't know what you want to really achieve behind that. You should maybe process your data from the SQL Database into an adequate data structure and then render the generated structure ...